# Cannot compile less sources - Play framework

Tags: scala, less, playframework-2.3

I was trying to add less sources to my project. I inclueded to my build.sbt these lines:

`includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"`

`excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"`

`LessKeys.compress := true`

and to plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.4")
```

Throws it to my console after trying to compile less sources.

> Caused by: com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$JsTaskFailure: [object
>   Object]
>   (/home/chabeee/Projects/test/project/target/node-modules/webjars/less/lib/less/parser.js#604)

**What should I do with this?**

**EDIT**

```
#loginForm {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 42%;
}
.login-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #999;
}
.login-panel {
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px 50px 50px 
}
a#login-button:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2991 possible caused by a empty Less file?

Comment: Nope, It has content

Comment: and you have only one .less file?

Comment: I had, but i created new less files to debug which weren't empty. Same happened.

Comment: did you already have tried a different version of sbt-less? `addSbtPlugin ( "com.typesafe.sbt"  %  "sbt-less"  %  "1.0.0" )` default or `addSbtPlugin ( "com.typesafe.sbt"  %  "sbt-less"  %  "1.0.5" )` newest

Comment: Firstly, I tried with 1.0.0, after the exception, I changed it to 1.0.4.
I will try it with 1.0.5 :)

Comment: Tried 1.0.5, didn't worked for me :/

Comment: Can you add your less files?

Comment: I added my less content. I made another file, but I deleted it because I only created it for test.